# Python 3: Specific user input check

Tags: python-3.x

Just to clarify, I know next to nothing in python 3 so searching gave me answers that were still difficult for me to understand

I am following a tutorial, a memory game in python 3

I have this piece of code written so far:

```
board_invisible = list("ABCD") * 2
board_visible = list("________")
revealed = []

while True:

    print(" ".join(board_visible))
    print("0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7")


    user_input = input()

    if user_input == "q":
        break

    if len(revealed) == 2:
        for i in revealed:
            board_visible[i] = '_'

            revealed = []

    board_index = int(user_input)
    board_visible[board_index] = board_invisible[board_index]

    revealed.append(board_index)
```

My assignment was to find a way to catch any user input that is not a number from 0 to 7 and print wrong  input if that was the case.

Now, I have seen a few solutions for doing this, but beforehand, I had came up with my own solution, which did not work. It was as follow :

```
if user_input == "0" or "1" or "2" or "3" or "4" or "5" or "6" or "7":
        continue
    else:
        print("wrong input")
```

I had integrated it like this :

```
board_invisible = list("ABCD") * 2
board_visible = list("________")
revealed = []

while True:

    print(" ".join(board_visible))
    print("0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7")

    user_input = input()

    if user_input == "q":
        break

    if user_input == "0" or "1" or "2" or "3" or "4" or "5" or "6" or "7":
        continue

    else:
        print("wrong input")

    if len(revealed) == 2:
        for i in revealed:
            board_visible[i] = '_'

            revealed = []

    board_index = int(user_input)
    board_visible[board_index] = board_invisible[board_index]

    revealed.append(board_index)
```

The result was that python would completely ignore my "if condition" that I hoped would prevent the user from entering anything else than a number from 0 to 7.

I would like to know why this piece of code did not work for that purpose:

```
if user_input == "0" or "1" or "2" or "3" or "4" or "5" or "6" or "7":
    continue

else:
    print("wrong input")
```

I should also mention the suggested solution I had seen, which only half worked for me: (changed some variable names for simplicity's sake)

```
board_visible = list("________")
board = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] * 2 
flipped = []

while True:

    print(" ".join(board_visible))
    print("0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7")

    if len(flipped) == 2:
        for i in flipped:
            board_visible[i] = '_'
        flipped = []

    user_input = input()

    if user_input == "q":
        break

    if user_input.isdigit():

        idx = int(user_input)

        if idx < len(board):

            board_visible[idx] = board_invisible[idx]

            flipped.append(idx)

            continue

        print("wrong input")
```

<strike>but for some reason it only wrote "wrong input" when I entered an "out of range number". Entering a character (anything else than an int) simply continued to run my program as if I did not entered anything.</strike>

the last line "print("wrong input") has a wrong indentation. now it works, but I still am glad that I could learn that there is more than one way to do this, thanks to the answers given in this thread.

Comment: You should clarify about "did not work", please explain the behavior. My guess (on a mobile so can't prove it) is that you are calling `continue` which would advance to the next iteration of your `while` loop. Meaning you'd want to do something more like `if user_input not in [x for x in range(10)]: print("message"); continue` (minimized and not necessarily the best solution, but at least gives an idea).

Comment: "did not work" meant that python would simply ignore the problematic "if condition". For example, I would input "9" and the message "wrong input was not printed as I had hoped. There was not error message either, the code would execute just as if I had never entered these lines of code. but I see what you are trying to explain except I am not sure how I would use that for my program. I try looking into that some more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That condition returns `True` if `user_input == "0"` and returns "1" if `user_input != "0"` because `==` has more precedence than `or`. And because that how `or` works, it returns the first operand if it is "truthy" (non empty lists, non empty strings, True, etc...) else it returns the second operand.

Example:

```
 In [8]: 1 == 1 or "1" or "2" or "3" or "4" or "5" or "6" or "7"
 Out[8]: True

 In [9]: 1 == 0  or "1" or "2" or "3" or "4" or "5" or "6" or "7"
 Out[9]: '1'
```

You have different ways to check if the input is what you want:

```
 if user_input in "01234567": # ...
 if user_input in [ "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" ]: # ...

 import re
 #...
 if re.match(r'^[0-7]$', user_input): # ...
```

Also note the body of your `if` is incorrect, `continue` skips the rest of the current `while` iteration, so if the user inputs a value between 0 and 7 the program just returns to the beginning of the `while`.

You should write something like:

```
 if user_input not in "01234567": # Notice the `not in` operator
     print("wrong input")
     continue # To skip the rest of the while and ask the user to input a number again
```

You may understand the semantics of `continue` with the following example:

```
 # Lets print even numbers
 for i in range(20):
     if i % 2 != 0: # if it is odd
         continue   # skip the rest of this for
     print(i)       # prints i (only even numbers reach this point)
```

Comment: I did not fully understand your answer. (because I cannot see how I would be able to insert this into my program example) but I can see that I had the wrong idea about  how "or" works. I'll try to read some more about it

Comment: I have edited the answer, there were two errors, one was the implementation of the condition, and the other is that `continue` doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: Checking the comments of the question nerdwaller detected the problem with `continue` before me :)

Comment: wow this edited comment of yours really did the trick! I get it completely now. Before I had read your answer, I was gonna go with my solution that I edited in. but I like what you suggest